# Selenium Firefox Driver reading from Hosts file

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to avoid running this particular selenium script in a production environment. When this test is ran manually, I change my /etc/hosts file accordingly.

```
xx.x.xxx.xx    www.url.com
```

What is a practical way of passing the test environment IP to the driver? Or perhaps have the driver read from the host file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest providing a command line argument that your selenium scripts can reference. This argument can contain the the environment ip address you wish to run your tests against. Or another possible solution would to have a property file included in your selenium project that contains environments you use for testing with their appropriate ip addresses. You can parse this file and pull out the environment you want to run against.

Comment: I've passed it as a command line argument, the driver takes it and runs; however I pause the script towards the end and install a 'show IP' extension to the driver instance and it's not reflecting as the one I passed. Perhaps I'll have better results with your property file suggestion. I'll give it a go.